# How to add the weeks with no items sold as zero values to my SQL query?

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2013

Basically I have this query below, that gives me the number of sales per week, but it skips the weeks where there were no sales for a specific item. I would like it also to display those as 0 values.
And by the way, is it possible to merge the two queries below? I tried but couldn't get the joins to work.

```
SELECT tblWeek.WeekNum, [Query - Sales].ModelName, Count([Query - Sales].OutDate) AS CountOfOutDate
FROM tblWeek LEFT JOIN [Query - Sales] ON tblWeek.WeekNum = [Query - Sales].WeekNumber
GROUP BY tblWeek.WeekNum, [Query - Sales].ModelName
HAVING ((([Query - Sales].ModelName) Is Not Null))
 ORDER BY [Query - Sales].ModelName;
```

Query - Sales:

```
SELECT DDL_Items.ModelName, DDL_Items.OutDate, DDL_Models.Type, DatePart("ww",[OutDate],2) AS WeekNumber
FROM DDL_Models INNER JOIN DDL_Items ON DDL_Models.ModelName = DDL_Items.ModelName;
```

[image]

Thank you and best regards,

Francisco

Comment: If `tblWeek.WeekNum` has no data for the missing weeks, then these dates won't appear in your result set.  If this be the case, you would have to use a calendar table to bring in this information.

Comment: tblWeek.WeekNum is a calendar table. I mean, this table only has numbers from 1 to 53 (week numbers).

Comment: What is currently being displayed for those weeks if not zero?

Comment: Only weeks that have no items sold at all get displayed as 0. But if there is a certain item sold on a given week, that week wont show up as empty for the rest of items.

Comment: I think you should show us sample data, though someone might be able to answer with just this.

Comment: For example:
MODEL NAME | WEEK | Quantity
Item 1              |     43   |       12
Item 1              |     44   |        7
Item 2              |     43   |       14
Item 2              |     45   |        9

Item 2 Week 44 doesnt have any values, I would like it to have a 0.

Comment: Try getting rid of the HAVING statement.   If I'm reading correctly ( it's early in the morning) the values for model name will be null if there are no sales for that week

Comment: That is just a filter for rows with empty model names. If I remove the only difference will be that if I have no items at all sold on a given week, that week won't show up. But if I have Item 1 sold on that week, and Item 2 not sold on that week, item 2 will have no record on that week.

Comment: Right.   If an item has zero sales then does it exist in the sales table or not?  If it's null then you've filtered it out, and you won't see that week.

Comment: Let me try to explain it in a better way.

If I have Item 1 sold on weeks 1, 3 and 4.
Item 2, sold on weeks, 1 and 3.
I want to have the 2 items, display the 4 weeks, and the zero values on the ones that have no sales. I can remove the having statement, that will just add weeks with no sales across all items (I only have one such case, that would be week 2 on the example above).

Comment: I don't think that explanation is much better; you can't both display the missing weeks and leave them out.

Comment: Okay, so lets say I remove the having.
Item 2 still has no data for the 4th week. No 0, nothing.

Comment: Added picture, to see if you can understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing you want to do is create a Cartesian Join between your model name and the weeks.  Something like:

```
SELECT DISTINCT [Query - Sales].ModelName, tblWeek.WeekNum
FROM [Query - Sales]
LEFT JOIN tblWeek
```

This will create one record for every week for every model name.

Then, you want to join the actual data to this query:

```
SELECT qryA.*, Count([Query - Sales].OutDate) AS CountOfOutDate
FROM (
SELECT DISTINCT [Query - Sales].ModelName, tblWeek.WeekNum
FROM [Query - Sales]
LEFT JOIN tblWeek 
) as qryA
LEFT JOIN [Query - Sales]   
   ON tblWeek.WeekNum = qryA.WeekNumber
GROUP BY tblWeek.WeekNum, qryA.ModelName
HAVING qryA.ModelName Is Not Null
ORDER BY qryA.ModelName;
```

Comment: This really sounds like what I need. Basically creating a combination of all the weeks/models. But I am not managing to make the first query work. I am getting a syntax error in the from clause.

Comment: Not sure.  I know in Access if you just add both tblWeek and [Query - Sales] using Design Mode and don't join them, it will create your cartesian join.  Try doing that and let Access write your SQL for you, and then use that in the larger (2nd) query.

Answer (score 0):

Full code below in case someone is looking for the answer:

```
SELECT qryA.ModelName, qryA.WeekNum, Count([Query - Sales].OutDate) AS CountOfOutDate
FROM qryA LEFT JOIN [Query - Sales] ON qryA.WeekNum = [Query - Sales].WeekNumber
GROUP BY qryA.ModelName, qryA.WeekNum;
```